# Iterate on an object and averaging some values

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure `allDataJson` like this:

```
[ { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'POL',
    coverage: 95.13 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'DIPH',
    coverage: 95.14 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'TET',
    coverage: 95.44 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'PER',
    coverage: 95.12 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'EP B',
    coverage: 94.72 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'HIB',
    coverage: 94.33 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'MEASLES',
    coverage: 91.06 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'MUMPS',
    coverage: 91.06 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'RUB',
    coverage: 91.06 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'VAR',
    coverage: 1.86 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men C',
    coverage: 89.33 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'PNC',
    coverage: 91.84 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'EP A',
    coverage: 0.87 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'ROTA',
    coverage: 6.39 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men B',
    coverage: 0 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men ACYW',
    coverage: 0 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'POL',
    coverage: 90.86 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'DIPH',
    coverage: 90.77 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'TET',
    coverage: 91.32 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'PER',
    coverage: 90.77 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'EP B',
    coverage: 90.67 }, ...]
```

I want to create another `dataJson` object similar to `allDataJson` but that averages some values.

For example, in 2016 I want to create a new `DTP` vaccine value that calculates the average between the values of `DIPH`, `TET` and `PER`.

Also in 2016 I want to create an `MMRV` vaccine whose value is the average between the `MEASLES`, `MUMPS`, `RUB` and `VAR` values.

So `dataJson` will looks like (it contains the new values, those not modified and does not contain those of which I have averaged):

```
[ { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'POL',
    coverage: 95.13 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'DTP',
    coverage: 95.23 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'EP B',
    coverage: 94.72 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'HIB',
    coverage: 94.33 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'MMRV',
    coverage:  68.76 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men C',
    coverage: 89.33 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'PNC',
    coverage: 91.84 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'EP A',
    coverage: 0.87 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'ROTA',
    coverage: 6.39 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men B',
    coverage: 0 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    vaccine: 'Men ACYW',
    coverage: 0 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'POL',
    coverage: 90.86 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'DTP',
    coverage:  90.95 },
  { year: 2016,
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Valle d\'Aosta',
    vaccine: 'EP B',
    coverage: 90.67 }, ...]
```

This is my code:

```
global.allDataJson = []; // all data
global.dataJson = []; // data I'm interested in

methods.elaborate = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < allDataJson.length; i++) {
        var val = allDataJson[i];
        switch(val.year) {
            case 2016:
                if(val.region == 'Piemonte') {
                    var diph = 0;
                    var tet = 0;
                    var per = 0;
                    var mea = 0;
                    var mum = 0;
                    var rub = 0;
                    var vari = 0;
                    if(val.vaccine == 'DIPH') {
                        diph = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'TET') {
                        tet = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'PER') {
                        per = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'MEASLES') {
                        mea = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'MUMPS') {
                        mum = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'RUB') {
                        rub = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else if(val.vaccine == 'VAR') {
                        vari = val.coverage;
                    }
                    else {
                        var newObj = createJsonObject(2016, val.country, val.vaccine, 'Piemonte', val.coverage);
                        dataJson.push(newObj);
                    }
                    // create DTP value
                    var avgDtp = (diph + tet + per)/3;
                    var newObj = createJsonObject(2016, val.country, 'DTP', 'Piemonte', avgDtp);
                    dataJson.push(newObj);
                    // create MMRV value
                    var avgMmrv = (mea + mum + rub + vari)/4;
                    var newObj = createJsonObject(2016, val.country, 'MMRV', 'Piemonte', avgMmrv);
                    dataJson.push(newObj);
                }
                if(val.region == 'Lombardia') {
                    // same thing for another region
                }
                // same thing for each region

                break;

            case 2000:
                // similar thing for each year
                break;

            default:
                console.log('Switch err in elaborate() function');
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: You should have a look at array functions such as *reduce()*.

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert, can you be more precise? I have used the reduce() function sometimes but in very simple examples. Now I don't know how to use it.

Comment: `var avgDtp = (diph + tet + per)/3;` This line will not work properly until each of those variables has been populated.

Comment: I don't get the point of doing `(diph + tet + per)/3` and `(mea + mum + rub + vari)/4;` since all of them equals 0 except for one.. Shouldn't it be like [this](https://pastebin.com/B4i8FACk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a variable to maintain your filtering configuration:

```
global.config = [
  {
    year: 2016,
    vaccine: 'DTP',
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    combinedData: [ 'DIPH', 'TET', 'PER' ]
  },
  {
    year: 2016,
    vaccine: 'MMRV',
    country: 'Italy',
    region: 'Piemonte',
    combinedData: [ 'MEASLES', 'MUMPS', 'RUB', 'VAR' ]
  },
  // and so on
]
```

and pass it as parameter to the function `elaborate`:

```
methods.elaborate = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<config.length; i++ ) {
    var filterDataJson = allDataJson.filter(function(data) {
      return data.country === data.country && data.region === config[i].region && data.year === config[i].year && config[i].combinedData.includes(data.vaccine);
    })

    if (filterDataJson.length > 0) {
      var average = 0;
      for (var j=0; j<filterDataJson.length; j++) {
        average += filterDataJson[j].coverage / filterDataJson.length;
      }
      var newObj = createJsonObject(config[i].year, config[i].vaccine, config[i].country, config[i].region, average);
      dataJson.push(newObj);
    } else {
      console.log("Some meaningful error message here");
    }
  }
}
```

Never use switch and if-else with so many sub-conditions unless you have good reason to do so.

EDIT: if the vaccines are the same for all regions, then you can group them like this

```
global.config = [
  {
    year: 2016,
    vaccine: 'DTP',
    country: 'Italy',
    regions: ['Piemonte', 'Lombardia', 'Sicilia', 'Sardegna', ...],
    combinedData: [ 'DIPH', 'TET', 'PER' ]
  },
  {
    year: 2016,
    vaccine: 'MMRV',
    country: 'Italy',
    regions: ['Piemonte', 'Lombardia', 'Sicilia', 'Sardegna', ...],
    combinedData: [ 'MEASLES', 'MUMPS', 'RUB', 'VAR' ]
  },
  // and so on
]
```

and `elaborate` function needs to be twisted a bit:

```
methods.elaborate = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<config.length; i++ ) {
    for (var k=0; k<config[i].regions.length; k++) {
      var filterDataJson = allDataJson.filter(function(data) {
        return data.country === data.country && data.region === config[i].regions[k] && data.year === config[i].year && config[i].combinedData.includes(data.vaccine);
      })

      if (filterDataJson.length > 0) {
        var average = 0;
        for (var j=0; j<filterDataJson.length; j++) {
          average += filterDataJson[j].coverage / filterDataJson.length;
        }
        var newObj = createJsonObject(config[i].year, config[i].vaccine, config[i].country, config[i].regions[k], average);
        dataJson.push(newObj);
      } else {
        console.log("Some meaningful error message here");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this! There is only one problem. I have to do groupings for many regions (21 regions) so I would have a config object full of many `{year: 2016, vaccine: 'DTP', country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', combinedData: ['DIPH', 'TET', 'PER']}` where the only thing that changes is the name of the region. How could I improve? My regions are `['Piemonte', 'Lombardia', 'Sicilia', 'Sardegna', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all data in an object, because the wanted information for calculating the averages are spreaded ocer more than one object of the given data.

For collecting, a `groups` array is used to group all data by year, country and region.

After building of the object, the averages are calculated and by maintaining an object which reflects the groups and the averages for pushing to the result set.

```js
function iter(object, index, temp) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        temp = Object.assign({}, temp, { [groups[index]]: k });
        if (index + 1 < groups.length) {
            iter(object[k], index + 1, temp);
            return;
        }
        Object
            .keys(averages)
            .forEach(a => temp[a] = averages[a].reduce((s, l) => s + (object[k][l] || 0), 0) / averages[a].length);
        result.push(temp);
    });
}

var data = [{ year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'POL', coverage: 95.13 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'DIPH', coverage: 95.14 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'TET', coverage: 95.44 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'PER', coverage: 95.12 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'EP B', coverage: 94.72 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'HIB', coverage: 94.33 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'MEASLES', coverage: 91.06 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'MUMPS', coverage: 91.06 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'RUB', coverage: 91.06 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'VAR', coverage: 1.86 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'Men C', coverage: 89.33 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'PNC', coverage: 91.84 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'EP A', coverage: 0.87 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'ROTA', coverage: 6.39 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'Men B', coverage: 0 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Piemonte', vaccine: 'Men ACYW', coverage: 0 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Valle d\'Aosta', vaccine: 'POL', coverage: 90.86 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Valle d\'Aosta', vaccine: 'DIPH', coverage: 90.77 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Valle d\'Aosta', vaccine: 'TET', coverage: 91.32 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Valle d\'Aosta', vaccine: 'PER', coverage: 90.77 }, { year: 2016, country: 'Italy', region: 'Valle d\'Aosta', vaccine: 'EP B', coverage: 90.67 }],
    object = {},
    groups = ['year', 'country', 'region'],
    averages = { DTP: ['DIPH', 'TET', 'PER'], MMRV: ['MEA', 'MUM', 'RUB', 'VARI'] },
    result = [];

data.forEach(o => groups.reduce((r, g) => r[o[g]] = r[o[g]] || {}, object)[o.vaccine] = o.coverage);

iter(object, 0, {});

console.log(result);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```